# js scripts written in html not working in staging

Tags: javascript

Here I am using zoomsl for images to have a zoom effect. I have included the script in this particular file and its not working. I tried external file concept also, but it doesn't work. All the pages including the script tags are not showing the script functionality. It works well in normal html files but when changed to staging this happens. All the js external files are loading in inspect element, but script tags included are not working

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
  <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.88.1">
  <title>Destina1 International</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="package-tabs single-product">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
          <div class="zoomed-images">
            <ul>
              <li><img src="images/14011.jpg" data-src="images/14011.jpg" class="small_img lazyload"></li>
              <li><img src="images/14012.jpg" data-src="images/14012.jpg" class="small_img lazyload"></li>
              <li><img src="images/14013.jpg" data-src="images/14013.jpg" class="small_img lazyload"></li>
              <li><img src="images/14014.jpg" data-src="images/14014.jpg" class="small_img lazyload"></li>
            </ul>
            <img src="images/14011.jpg" data-src="images/14011.jpg" class="big_img lazyload">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
          <div class="top-content">
            <h2 class="heading1">MYSH02 ( SAPPHIRE BIO MATRIX )</h2>
            <h4>Product Code : MYSH02</h4>
            <h4>CV : 200</h4>
            <h4><span>Availability: <span id="green">In Stock</span></span>
            </h4>
            <div class="rating">
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              <span>4.9(173)</span>
            </div>
            <h3 class="heading2">RM 1693.00</h3>
            <button class="btn-black-radius">Add to Cart</button>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom-content">
            <h3>WHAT IT IS :</h3>
            <h4>DESTINA 1 SAPPHIRE COMBO 3</h4>
            <p style="font-size: 13px;line-height: 22px;font-weight: 400;overflow-y: auto;max-height: 130px;">Researches shown prolonged and repeated exposure to aggressive Electromagnetic Frequencies (EMF) and Electromagnetic Radiation(EMR) causes a measurable stress response and negative shifts in the body's key energetic systems such as the bio
              electric field. Studies have linked electropollution to health concerns like fatigue and hyper-tension, as well as potentially much more dangerous conditions.</p>
            <p style="font-size: 13px;line-height: 22px;font-weight: 400;overflow-y: auto;max-height: 130px;">The Advance Scalar Energy from the “D1 Bio Matrix Shield” will strengthen the body's bio field preventing electro-magnetic waves from affecting one's health. “D1 Bio Matrix Shield” is the first-line defense against electro pollution, “can
              be used on any appliance or device emitting electromagnetic frequencies (EMF) or electromagnetic radiation (EMR), such as mobile phones, home phones, cars, microwaves, computers, game consoles, home appliances, etc. If it plugs and plays
              on DC or AC currents, protect it with “D1 Bio Matrix Shield”.</p>
            <p style="margin: 15px 0;font-size: 13px;font-weight: 600;">Do You Want To Change The Package? <a href="products.html" style="color: #38539a;"> Click Here</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lazyload@2.0.0-rc.2/lazyload.js"></script>
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
  <script src="js/zoomsl.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".small_img").hover(function() {
        $(".big_img").attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".big_img").imagezoomsl({
        zoomrange: [3, 3]
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Look in your network tab to see where the files are supposed to load from. You can also use CDN instead to not worry about where the files loads and to speed up loading. right now you use CDN only for one file. Why?